# Help proving this Convolution Integral:

Tags: definite-integrals, convolution

Can someone give me the steps for proving the following integral:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{t}\left(t-\tau\right)^{-1/2}\tau^{-\alpha}d\tau=\frac{\Gamma\left(1-\alpha\right)}{\Gamma\left(3/2-\alpha\right)}t^{1/2-\alpha}$

**Other Information:**

$t>0$

$0\leq\alpha<1$

I have obtained the above solution using Mathematica, but I want to learn the steps. This is not my HOMEWORK! I am learning convolution and PDEs on my own. Thanks!

**EDIT** I have also obtained the above solution of the integral using Laplace transform. But I am interested in learning the algebraic steps/solution without going to Laplace transform.

Comment: Do you know Laplace transform?

Comment: Yes. But I want to avoid Laplace Transform in this particular situation. I just want to see algebraic steps/solution (if any).

Comment: Substitute $\tau = t\cdot x$, recognise the Beta-function.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: Thank you. I would like to accept your answer but you have given the answer as a comment. 

Before today I did not know if there was such a thing as Beta Function and I learned it, and proved the above! Thanks!